# Rails public_activity gem rspec setting error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, public-activity

I am integrating [public_activity](https://github.com/chaps-io/public_activity) (version 1.5) gem to my Rails 4 app.

Trying to set up tests as specified in their wiki, I write the following:

```
#spec_helper.rb
require 'public_activity/testing'

PublicActivity.enabled = false
```

However, trying to run my specs I get the following error:

> /my_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:24:in `<top (required)>': undefined method`enabled=' for PublicActivity:Module (NoMethodError)

Looking at Public Activity module [source code](https://github.com/chaps-io/public_activity/blob/1-5-stable/lib/public_activity.rb) I can clearly see `enable=` method there.

Can you please advise me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: please confirm whether enabled should be an instance method vs class method?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source, `testing.rb` does not require `PublicActivity` where `enabled=` is defined, so I believe you'll need to do

```
require 'public_activity'
require 'public_activity/testing'
```

like it's done in their [`test_helper.rb`](https://github.com/chaps-io/public_activity/blob/master/test/test_helper.rb#L18).

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://github.com/chaps-io/public_activity) seems to be incorrect.

<strike>I was able to get it to work like this:</strike>

```
PublicActivity::Config.instance.enabled = false
```

**Update: Jan Klimo's answer is the correct way.**